# Is it possible to insert a comment tag into an xml using simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using SimpleXML to build a document, and wondering whether it is possible to insert comment tag to the document like this:

```
<root>
  <!-- some comment -->
  <value>
</root>
```

**EDIT**:

The comment is somewhere in the middle of the document.

```
<root>
  <tag1 />
  <!-- some comment -->
  <value />
</root>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, SimpleXML doesn't handle comments. As it's been mentionned, DOM does handle comments but it's a kind of a bother to use for simple stuff, compared to SimpleXML.

My recommendation: try [SimpleDOM](http://code.google.com/p/simpledom/). It's an extension to SimpleXML, so everything works the same and it has a bunch of useful methods to deal with DOM stuff.

For instance, `insertComment($content, $mode)` can `append` to or insert comments `before` or `after` a given node. For example:

```
include 'SimpleDOM.php';

$root = simpledom_load_string('<root><value/></root>');

$root->value->insertComment(' mode: append ', 'append');
$root->value->insertComment(' mode: before ', 'before');
$root->value->insertComment(' mode: after ', 'after');

echo $root->asPrettyXML();
```

...will echo

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <!-- mode: before -->
  <value>
    <!-- mode: append -->
  </value>
  <!-- mode: after -->
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, I might find that useful too. Not heard of that library before.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, but apparently you can [use DomDocument as a workaround (german)](http://www.schadeck.eu/index.php/2007/07/20/allgemein/mit-simplexmlelement-cdata-comment-sections-erzeugen/):

```
    $oNodeOld = dom_import_simplexml($oParent);
    $oDom = new DOMDocument();
    $oDataNode = $oDom->appendChild($oDom->createElement($sName));
    $oDataNode->appendChild($oDom->createComment($sValue));
    $oNodeTarget = $oNodeOld->ownerDocument->importNode($oDataNode, true);
    $oNodeOld->appendChild($oNodeTarget);
    return simplexml_import_dom($oNodeTarget);
```

But then again, why not use DOM directly?

Answer (score 5):

There's actually a dirty trick, based on the fact that `addChild` doesn't check if the element name is valid:

```
$root->addChild('!-- Your comment --><dummy');
```

When using `$root->asXML()` you'd get a string like this:

```
<root><!-- Your comment --><dummy/></root>
```

You may notice it generated an empty `<dummy>` element as well, but it's the price to pay. Don't try to add a value, it would only mess everything up. Use *only* in conjunction with `asXML()`.

Well, I *did* say it's a dirty trick. **I don't recommend using this in production**, but only for debugging/testing purposes.

Comment: Is there a typo in your first command (missing `<` before ,`!`)?

Comment: @beroe Nope, it's exactly as it is. Just try.

Comment: OK, cool. I see now that it gets wrapped in `< />` which supplies the "missing" brackets. Dirty trick indeed :^)

Comment: For my purposes, I ended up just going with the boring solution of  `$comment = $dom->createComment("My Comment"); $dom->appendChild($comment);`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick and easy solution:

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
$xml->element->comment->sample = 12;
$xml_str = $xml->asXML();
$xml_str = str_replace(['<comment>', '</comment>'], ['<!--', '-->'], $xml_str)
echo $xml_str;
```

```
<root> <!-- <sample>12</sample> --> </root>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$CommentNode = $xml->createComment("some comment");
$root->appendChild($CommentNode);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I believe this was meant for `DOMDocument` object. However, this does not relate to the question which explicitly asked about SimpleXML object.