# simplexml with multi line comment

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

Is it possible to have a multi line comment in xml, when parsing via php using simplexml?

I have tried this:

```
<!--
     my comment
     fsdfs
  -->
```

But get: Comment not terminated

Do I really have to:

```
<!-- my comment -->
<!-- fsdfs -->
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757396/how-do-i-comment-out-a-block-of-tags-in-xml What parser gives you that error?

Comment: It would seem that simplexml doesn't handle comments very well. There are other APIs available that handle multiline comments just fine that you can use besides simplexml if this is a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139012/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-comment-tag-into-an-xml-using-simplexml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example appears to be valid XML, and should not generate an error. The code below was tested, and generates no errors or warnings in PHP v5.4.7.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$string = <<< EOT
<xml>
    <foo>Hello</foo>
    <bar>World</bar>
    <!-- This is a single line comment. -->
    <!--
    This is a
    multi-line comment.
    -->
</xml>
EOT;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($xml);
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  ["bar"]=>
  string(5) "World"
  ["comment"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the comment lines starting with `--` which was causing the error to start with

Comment: How do you add multiple options to: `simplexml_load_file($filename, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)`

Comment: I want to try adding: `LIBXML_COMPACT

Comment: @JohnMagnolia You cannot use "--" anywhere in a comment; it is that, not the line breaks, which are breaking your code. Technically, it is not the sequence `-->` which terminates the comment, `--` on its own sort-of terminates it straight away (it gets a bit confusing when you go into the details, but bottom line is don't use that sequence in a comment!)