# How to generate an XML with comments with CakePHP?

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, comments, xml-comments

CakePHP provides a functionality to generate XML documents/strings from an array (s. CakePHP docu -> Core Libraries -> Utilities -> Xml -> [Transforming an array into a string of XML](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#transforming-an-array-into-a-string-of-xml)).

Simple example:

```
$xmlArray = array(
    'project' => array(
        '@id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Name of project, as tag',
        '@' => 'Value of project'
    )
);
$xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($xmlArray);
$xmlString = $xmlObject->asXML();
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project id="1">Value of project<name>Name of project, as tag</name></project>
```

Now I'd like to generate an XML with one or more comments, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- here is a comment -->
<project id="1">Value of project<name>Name of project, as tag</name></project>
```

Is it possible? How to do that?

---

COMMENT:

This question was marked as duplicate of "[Is it possible to insert a comment tag into an xml using simplexml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139012/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-comment-tag-into-an-xml-using-simplexml)". But it does NOT duplicate that question, since it's more specific and refers to the XML comments in the context of the CakePHP XML generation -- and not to the "plain" PHP or `SimpleXML`.

Answer (score 1):

No, but as you're actually creating a **SimpleXMLElement** you can insert the comment your own.

See the existing Q&A of that topic:

- [Is it possible to insert a comment tag into an xml using simplexml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139012/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-comment-tag-into-an-xml-using-simplexml)